# Connecting to Hbase remotely from Tomcat 6 Servlet

Tags: tomcat, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hbase

I am not an expert on Hbase and have been flaying through threads of Hbase remote connection but with no luck.

I am running a Hbase/Hadoop single cluster on an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 10.4). I am also running a servlet on a tomcat6 server in another ec 2instance. The plan is for the servlet to write and read to the remote Hbase instance. The servlet is running a contextlistener with some java routines (ServletContextListener).

Now if I run the java routines as a runnable jar instead of a servlet all is fine. It connects to Hbase and writes/reads from table. But on tomcat6 it just freezes when attempting to connect to the Hbase instance.

```
2012-10-01 11:11:40,751 [Timer-4] INFO  com.myApp.foundation.access.HBaseHandler  initialise(..) - Initialisation HbaseHandler configuration ...
2012-10-01 11:11:40,763 [Timer-4] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  <init>(..) - java.io.IOException: config()
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.<init>(HBaseConfiguration.java:33)
    at com.myApp.foundation.access.HBaseHandler.initialise(HBaseHandler.java:507)
    at com.myApp.foundation.access.HBaseHandler.<init>(HBaseHandler.java:53)
    at com.myApp.foundation.access.HBaseHandler.getInstance(HBaseHandler.java:500)
    at com.myApp.foundation.hbase.StorableRow.<clinit>(StorableRow.java:40)
    at com.myApp.foundation.entities.Article.storeToHbase(Article.java:257)
    at com.myApp.task.impl.HBaseArticlePersisterTask.process(HBaseArticlePersisterTask.java:101)
    at com.myApp.foundation.task.QueueTask.performTask(QueueTask.java:101)
    at com.myApp.runner.impl.HBasePersisterRunner$1.run(HBasePersisterRunner.java:46)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

2012-10-01 11:11:40,803 [Timer-4] INFO  com.myApp.foundation.access.HBaseHandler  initialise(..) - Config resource zookeeper.quorum: ip-10-10-10-10.eu-west-1.compute.internal

2012-10-01 11:11:40,803 [Timer-4] INFO  com.myApp.foundation.access.HBaseHandler  initialise(..) - Config resource zookeeper.clientPort: 2181

2012-10-01 11:11:40,804 [Timer-4] INFO  com.myApp.foundation.access.HBaseHandler  initialise(..) - Config resource hbase.master.info.port: 60010

2012-10-01 11:11:40,804 [Timer-4] INFO  com.myApp.foundation.access.HBaseHandler  initialise(..) - Config resource hbase.master.info.bindAddress: ip-10-10-10-10.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

I can telnet the HBase instance. In the servlet I included the hbase-site.xml. But as you can see from the log, the zookkeeper.quorum is getting picked up as well as the port number. All necessary ports are open on the Hbase instance.

Something is telling me tomcat6 policy configuration is to blame. But I don't see anything in the catalina logs. Are there any other logs I am missing or could guide me to the right logs?

Has someone experienced the same problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: UPDATE: I deployed the servlet on a ec2 instance with a newer version of ubuntu 12.0, and it worked. My old instance (the one not working) is running 9.10. Does this mean something to anyone? Thanks

Comment: It seems it was Tomcat6 security manager that was to blame after all. Enabled Tomcat "FINE" logging level in logging.properties.
This exposed an access permission exception for java.lang.RuntimePermission "shutdownHooks".
Which in turn exposed other needed permissions: